# Using user sessions for the rails web application in conjunction with authorization token for the rails API for mobile apps.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, session, cookies

I have a web application already built with its own end points. I am using devise for user registrations/login/logout, basically anything user related is using the session cookies. In the same application, I have separate endpoints for my rails API (used for its mobile application counter part). This API uses authorization tokens (and overriding some Devise methods like current_user) to allow access to the specific user model.

Is this going to give me problems down the line, if I am handling the user session cookies on our website but using authorization tokens on the mobile application? My biggest fear is security issues because we are going to be handling credit card information. The idea is to not use the user session cookies on the mobile application, but keep the web application the same.

The reason I am asking this is because I am having some trouble "logging in" on our web application if I make the web app go through our rails api end points. I am not sure how to safely carry the authorization token from one page to another so I don't make the user login every time.

I hope the way I explained it isn't too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about disabling cookies for your Api namespace? If, for example, you're using a BaseController.rb, you can add:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  before_action :destroy_session

  def destroy_session
    request.session_options[:skip] = true
  end
end
```